# Python importing class and functions from one file to another file

Tags: python

When i run the file2.py it is taking inputs but instead of displaying output i got an error like this,

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "file2.py", line 12, in module

ob3.f3()

File "file2.py", line 8, in f3

c = self.a + self.b

AttributeError: cl2 instance has no attribute 'a'

file1.py

```
class cl1:

    def f1(self):
        self.a = int(raw_input())
    def f2(self):
        self.b = int(raw_input())
ob1 = cl1
```

file2.py

```
from file1 import cl1

ob2 = cl1()

ob2.f1()

ob2.f2()

class cl2(cl1):

    def f3(self):

        c = self.a + self.b
        print c

ob3 = cl2()

ob3.f3()
```

Comment: You called `f1()` on `ob2`. So `ob2` was given the `a` attribute. You didn't call `f1()` on `ob3`. So `ob3` was never given the `a` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I got the result.

Answer (score 0):

`cl2` doesn't have instance vars `a` and `b` because you didn't create them in `cl2`, and `cl2` isn't derived from another class that does create them.

Did you possibly mean to declare `class cl2(cl1)` -- a child class?

Comment: Even though i derived the base class to sub class, again i got an same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `f1` and `f2` on `ob3`. Those instance variables haven't been created yet. The calls made on `ob2` do not relate to `ob3`.